# Docker : exec /usr/bin/sh: exec format error

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, dockerhub

I created a custom docker image and push it to docker hub but when I run it in CI/CD it gives me this error.

`exec /usr/bin/sh: exec format error`

Where :

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN pip3 install robotframework
```

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
robot-framework:
  image: rethkevin/rf:v1
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    - ls
    - pip3 --version
```

**Output**

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.1.0 (76984217)
  on runner zgjy8gPC
Preparing the "docker" executor
Using Docker executor with image rethkevin/rf:v1 ...
Pulling docker image rethkevin/rf:v1 ...
Using docker image sha256:d2db066f04bd0c04f69db1622cd73b2fc2e78a5d95a68445618fe54b87f1d31f for rethkevin/rf:v1 with digest rethkevin/rf@sha256:58a500afcbd75ba477aa3076955967cebf66e2f69d4a5c1cca23d69f6775bf6a ...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on runner-zgjy8gpc-project-1049-concurrent-0 via 1c8189df1d47...
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/reth.bagares/test-rf/.git/
Checking out 339458a3 as main...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
Using docker image sha256:d2db066f04bd0c04f69db1622cd73b2fc2e78a5d95a68445618fe54b87f1d31f for rethkevin/rf:v1 with digest rethkevin/rf@sha256:58a500afcbd75ba477aa3076955967cebf66e2f69d4a5c1cca23d69f6775bf6a ...
exec /usr/bin/sh: exec format error
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

any thoughts on this to resolve the error?

Comment: Can you provide the full job log output?

Comment: That error means wrong architecture eg arm64 code attempting to run on a x86-64 system.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

The problem is that you built this image for arm64/v8 -- but your runner is using a different architecture.

If you run:

```
docker image inspect rethkevin/rf:v1
```

You will see this in the output:

```
...
        "Architecture": "arm64",
        "Variant": "v8",
        "Os": "linux",
...
```

Try building and pushing your image from your GitLab CI runner so the architecture of the image will match your runner's architecture.

Alternatively, you can [build for multiple architectures](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/multi-arch/#build-and-run-multi-architecture-images) using `docker buildx` . Alternatively still, you could also run a GitLab runner on ARM architecture so that it can run the image for the architecture you built it on.

---

With modern versions of docker, you may also explicitly control the platform docker uses. Docker will use platform emulation if the specified platform is different from your native platform.

For example:

Using the `DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM` environment variable:

```bash
DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM="linux/amd64" docker build -t test .
```

Using the `--platform` argument, either in the CLI or in your dockerfile:

```bash
docker build --platform="linux/amd64" -t test .
```

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 ubuntu:jammy
```

Systems with docker desktop installed should already be able to do this. If your system is using docker without docker desktop, you may need to install the docker-buildx plugins explicitly.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to this, will try this. How can I check what architecture the runner has?

Comment: @rkevx21 it's almost certainly amd64 (x86_64) -- On Linux systems, you can run `uname -m` or `uname -a` to check. The easiest thing to do would be to build and push your image using your runner so that the image will match whatever it happens to be.

Comment: You are right. I was building image on Mac M1. Thus faced this issue.

Comment: Update docker image: ```FROM --platform=linux/amd64 yourbaseimage``` if you are on arm.

Comment: Just saved me from a lot of digging! Thanks all. adding `FROM --platform=linux/amd64 yourbaseimage` to my docker image was exactly what i needed

Comment: Note that you can also `docker pull` with `--platform` flag. e.g. `docker pull --platform amd64 node:20.10.0-alpine3.19`

Comment: This helped me I was building image in arm64 architecture (M3 pro) and running in x86_64 architecture in AWS Batch Job (EC2). I was able to fix this issue by adding --platform linux/amd64 in docker build command and amd64 is compatible with x86_64 architecture. Thanks

Answer (score 47):

In my case, I was building it using buildx

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -f ./Dockerfile -t image .
```

however the problem was in AWS lambda [image]

Answer (score 14):

There could be many reasons why this error occurs while working with containers:

1. Using the wrong script header such as adding a space in between.
2. Using some incompatible character encodings while writing the scripts
3. Non-matching CPU architecture
4. Missing file permissions

Demonestrate here the reason (3) with example:

rohits-MacBook> catalog % docker version

Its darwin/arm64 architectute of my Laptop and the same docker Engine is installed.

```
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.31
 Version:           20.10.23
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.18.10
 Git commit:        7155243
 Built:             Thu Jan 19 17:35:19 2023
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           desktop-linux
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Desktop 4.17.0 (99724)
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.23
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.18.10
  Git commit:       6051f14
  Built:            Thu Jan 19 17:31:28 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.18
  GitCommit:        2456e983eb9e37e47538f59ea18f2043c9a73640
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.4
  GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

#################################################

Executing in my current laptop

rohits-MacBook> catalog % make image

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build  -ldflags="-X github.ibm.com/cloud-sre/version.Major= -X github.ibm.com/cloud-sre/version.Minor= -X github.ibm.com/cloud-sre/version.Build= -X github.ibm.com/cloud-sre/version.Timestamp=202303170049" -o osscatimporter ./cmd/osscatimporter
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build  -ldflags="-X github.ibm.com/cloud-sre/version.Major= -X github.ibm.com/cloud-sre/version.Minor= -X github.ibm.com/cloud-sre/version.Build= -X github.ibm.com/cloud-sre/version.Timestamp=202303170049" -o osscatpublisher ./cmd/osscatpublisher
jq: error: Could not open file metadata.json: No such file or directory
docker buildx build --platform=linux/amd64 -t api-osscatalog:latest .
[+] Building 153.2s (11/11) FINISHED                                                                                                                         
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 560B                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker-virtual.artifactory.swg-devops.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.7                                            34.2s
 => [auth] ubi8/ubi-minimal:pull token for docker-virtual.artifactory.swg-devops.com                                                        0.0s
 => [1/5] FROM docker-virtual.artifactory.swg-devops.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.7@sha256:65a240ad8bd3f2fff3e18a22ebadc40da0b145616231fc1e1625  91.3s
 => => resolve docker-virtual.artifactory.swg-devops.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.7@sha256:65a240ad8bd3f2fff3e18a22ebadc40da0b145616231fc1e16251  0.0s
 => => sha256:0214a28336e387c66493c61bb394e86a18f3bea8dbc46de74a26f173ff553c89 429B / 429B                                                              0.0s
 => => sha256:591670a5d6a620931ec51c1e7436300894f5320e76e9737f0366fc62114addd4 6.23kB / 6.23kB                                                          0.0s
 => => sha256:d7c06497d5cebd39c0a4feb14981ec940b5c863e49903d320f630805b049cbff 39.28MB / 39.28MB                                                       90.8s
 => => sha256:65a240ad8bd3f2fff3e18a22ebadc40da0b145616231fc1e16251f3c6dee087a 1.47kB / 1.47kB                                                          0.0s
 => => extracting sha256:d7c06497d5cebd39c0a4feb14981ec940b5c863e49903d320f630805b049cbff                                                               0.4s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                       0.2s
 => => transferring context: 23.77MB                                                                                                                    0.2s
 => [2/5] RUN microdnf update && microdnf install procps ;                                                                                             27.5s
 => [3/5] COPY osscatimporter /                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [4/5] COPY mailtemplate.tmpl /                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [5/5] COPY osscatpublisher /                                                                                                                        0.0s 
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                  0.1s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                 0.1s 
 => => writing image sha256:8af2a24809c709c2ea80b1f3ed0c0d1dc1381c84219e0e779be43ab8542e8c0d                                                            0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/api-osscatalog:latest                                                                                                0.0s
```

##############################

rohits-MacBook> catalog % docker images

```
REPOSITORY       TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
api-catalog     latest    8af2a24809c7   9 seconds ago   140MB
```

######################################

rohits-MacBook> osscatalog % docker image inspect api-catalog

```
        "Architecture": "arm64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 148693891,
        "VirtualSize": 148693891,
```

Produces an  `arm64`  image

########################################

### Issue after running instance in its log file shows:

rohits-MacBook> api-osscatalog % kubectl -n api logs -f catimporter-rohit-gst45

```
exec /bin/sh: exec format error
rohits-MacBook> api-catalog %
```

### Comment:

This usually happens when you’re working on projects on a system with ARM architecture, like with the new Apple M-series chipsets. When you push a code to your production environment, which is using an x86 system, it results in the “exec user process caused: exec format error”. This is because every piece of code when converted to the lower level of instructions is different for both ARM and x86. Docker detects the Apple M1 Pro platform as “linux/arm64/v8“.

################## SOLUTION ########################

1.
`/cloud-sre/catalog/Makefile`
Change:
`docker build -t $(IMAGE_NAME):latest .`
To:
`docker buildx build --platform=linux/amd64 -t $(IMAGE_NAME):latest .`

2. But for the above to work, need to change the Dockerfile also
   `/cloud-sre/catalog/Dockerfile`
   Change:
   `FROM docker-virtual.artifactory.swg-devops.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.7`
   To:
   `FROM --platform=linux/amd64 docker-virtual.artifactory.swg-devops.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.7`

#################### TEST ######################

rohits-MacBook> catalog % docker images

```
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID   CREATED   SIZE
```

Deleted all image

#####################################

rohits-MacBook> catalog %
rohits-MacBook> catalog % make image

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build  -ldflags="-X github.ibm.com/cloud-sre/version.Major= -X github.ibm.com/cloud-sre/version.Minor= -X github.ibm.com/cloud-sre/version.Build= -X github.ibm.com/cloud-sre/version.Timestamp=202303170049" -o osscatimporter ./cmd/osscatimporter
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build  -ldflags="-X github.ibm.com/cloud-sre/version.Major= -X github.ibm.com/cloud-sre/version.Minor= -X github.ibm.com/cloud-sre/version.Build= -X github.ibm.com/cloud-sre/version.Timestamp=202303170049" -o osscatpublisher ./cmd/osscatpublisher
jq: error: Could not open file metadata.json: No such file or directory
docker buildx build --platform=linux/amd64 -t api-osscatalog:latest .
[+] Building 153.2s (11/11) FINISHED                                                                                                                         
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 560B                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker-virtual.artifactory.swg-devops.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.7                                            34.2s
 => [auth] ubi8/ubi-minimal:pull token for docker-virtual.artifactory.swg-devops.com                                                        0.0s
 => [1/5] FROM docker-virtual.artifactory.swg-devops.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.7@sha256:65a240ad8bd3f2fff3e18a22ebadc40da0b145616231fc1e1625  91.3s
 => => resolve docker-virtual.artifactory.swg-devops.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.7@sha256:65a240ad8bd3f2fff3e18a22ebadc40da0b145616231fc1e16251  0.0s
 => => sha256:0214a28336e387c66493c61bb394e86a18f3bea8dbc46de74a26f173ff553c89 429B / 429B                                                              0.0s
 => => sha256:591670a5d6a620931ec51c1e7436300894f5320e76e9737f0366fc62114addd4 6.23kB / 6.23kB                                                          0.0s
 => => sha256:d7c06497d5cebd39c0a4feb14981ec940b5c863e49903d320f630805b049cbff 39.28MB / 39.28MB                                                       90.8s
 => => sha256:65a240ad8bd3f2fff3e18a22ebadc40da0b145616231fc1e16251f3c6dee087a 1.47kB / 1.47kB                                                          0.0s
 => => extracting sha256:d7c06497d5cebd39c0a4feb14981ec940b5c863e49903d320f630805b049cbff                                                               0.4s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                       0.2s
 => => transferring context: 23.77MB                                                                                                                    0.2s
 => [2/5] RUN microdnf update && microdnf install procps ;                                                                                             27.5s
 => [3/5] COPY osscatimporter /                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [4/5] COPY mailtemplate.tmpl /                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [5/5] COPY osscatpublisher /                                                                                                                        0.0s 
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                  0.1s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                 0.1s 
 => => writing image sha256:8af2a24809c709c2ea80b1f3ed0c0d1dc1381c84219e0e779be43ab8542e8c0d                                                            0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/api-osscatalog:latest                                                                                                0.0s
```

##############################################

rohits-MacBook> catalog % docker images

```
REPOSITORY       TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
api-catalog   latest    8af2a24809c7   9 seconds ago   140MB
```

################################################
rohits-MacBook> catalog % docker image inspect api-catalog:latest

```
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 140425582,
```

— Which I used to get in my old laptop always.

############################################

Now checking the log from the new instance:

rohits-MacBook> api-ocatalog % kubectl -n api logs -f catimporter-rohit-9bzk9

```
INFO  19:53:29 osscatimporter Version: .. - 202303170049
INFO  19:53:29 sending *osscatimporter* Starting Run osscatimporter using the slack-webhook-url Slack webhook key.
Test COS connection passed: oss-rmc-data-test
Test COS connection passed: oss-rmc-emergency-test
AUDIT 19:53:30 Operating in read-only mode on all services and components found from all sources (with visibility=private and above)
INFO  19:53:30 Forcing -check-owner=true
INFO  19:53:30 Optional run action ENABLED:  Services
INFO  19:53:30 Optional run action ENABLED:  Tribes
INFO  19:53:30 Optional run action ENABLED:  Environments
INFO  19:53:30 Optional run action ENABLED:  Deployments
INFO  19:53:30 Optional run action ENABLED:  Monitoring
INFO  19:53:30 Optional run action ENABLED:  RMC
INFO  19:53:30 Optional run action ENABLED:  RMC-Rescan
INFO  19:53:30 Optional run action DISABLED: Environments-Native
INFO  19:53:30 Optional run action DISABLED: ProductInfo-Parts
INFO  19:53:30 Optional run action DISABLED: ProductInfo-Parts-Refresh
INFO  19:53:30 Optional run action DISABLED: ProductInfo-ClearingHouse
INFO  19:53:30 Optional run action DISABLED: Dependencies-ClearingHouse
INFO  19:53:30 Optional run action DISABLED: ScorecardV1
INFO  19:53:30 Optional run action DISABLED: Doctor
INFO  19:53:30 Skip reloading Segment and Tribe Info from ScorecardV1
```

No Error

Answer (score 6):

For developers having similar error on AWS codebuild -
I had this error when using AWS codebuild, the issue persists when you use different arch on the build stage and deploy stage. My build stage was building docker images on arm64 arch and deploying them on EC2 which was on `_86*64` arch. Changing the build arch to `_86*64` fixed the problem

Answer (score 5):

I got this error because I was trying to execute a Bash script without the shebang line at the top.

I resolved it by adding the shebang line at the top of the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
```

Comment: I had leading whitespace. Make sure that `#!..` is exactly on line 1 as the first char and that it points to a valid interpreter.

Answer (score 4):

You should also be sure that what you're calling is indeed an executable. We made this mistake:

```
COPY --from=build /usr/src/service/serviceExec /bin/service 
COPY --from=build /usr/config/file.txt /bin/service
RUN chmod a+x service
CMD ["./service"]
```

And the error was:

```
exec ./service: exec format error
```

The OS was not able to execute a txt file and threw a architecture-like error.

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was simply a missing shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) at the start of the startup script.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you built this image for arm64/v8 -- but your runner is using a different architecture.
This is mostly occur when we are using mac which is using amd64.
I have use ubuntu system and pull images and use those ubuntu pushed images in k8s environment for pod then this issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter this error while using a gitlab runner running on arm64 architecture, here is a solution using arm64 binary in Gitlab CI/CD pipeline.

```
release-tag:
  stage: release
  tags:
    - my-runner
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
  environment: production
  before_script:
    - 'command -v wget >/dev/null || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install wget -y )'
    - wget -O release-cli https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli/-/releases/v0.16.0/downloads/bin/release-cli-linux-arm64
    - chmod +x release-cli
  script:
    - echo "Creating release for tag $CI_COMMIT_TAG"
    - >
      ./release-cli
      --job-token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN
      --project-id $CI_PROJECT_ID
      --server-url https://gitlab.com
      create
      --name "Release $CI_COMMIT_TAG"
      --description "Version $CI_COMMIT_TAG released on $(date '+%m-%d-%Y at %H:%M:%S') from pipeline $CI_PIPELINE_ID details $CI_PIPELINE_URL"
      --tag-name $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      --released-at $(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```