# exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error

Tags: docker, kubernetes, next.js, dockerfile, azure-aks

I created a custom docker image for my nextjs app that i pushed to my azure container registry (ACR), in order to pull into the pod of my azure kubernetes (AKS) cluster, but the pod status says 'CrashLoopBackOff', and the pod logs reveal the error:

`exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error`

I've looked at this thread (as well as several other similar ones): [Docker : exec /usr/bin/sh: exec format error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73285601/docker-exec-usr-bin-sh-exec-format-error), and I found out I was building my image for the wrong architecture. I was building it on ARM whereas the architecture of my kubernetes node is Linux/AMD64. However, even after changing it, the pod is still logging the same error, and i'm certain that the image is built correctly now for amd64, and that the node architecture is amd64.

I ran this to build the image for amd64:
`docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t <container_url>/<container_image>:<tag> . --load`

I ran this to push the image to my azure container:
`docker push <container_url>/<container_image>:<tag>`

I ran this to verify the image does work locally:

`docker run --platform linux/amd64 -it --rm <acr_name>.azurecr.io/<image_name>:v0.1.0`

And, to verify the architecture of both the container and pod, I ran the following commands:

`docker image inspect <image_id>`

output:

```
[
    {
     ...,
     "Architecture": "amd64",
     "Os": "linux",
    }
]
```

`kubectl get nodes -o=jsonpath='{.items[0].status.nodeInfo.architecture}'`

output: 'amd64'

so the architectures appear to match.

I also tried adding a shebang # at the beginning of my dockerfile. Still, i can't seem to figure out why i'm getting the error.

Here's my dockerfile:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Use an official Node.js runtime as the parent image
FROM node:16

# Update and install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl gnupg

# Install Yarn
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y yarn

# Clean up
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy .npmrc or .yarnrc for private package access
COPY .npmrc .npmrc

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json (or yarn.lock) to the container
COPY package*.json ./

# Copy the application code to the container
COPY . .

# Install the application's dependencies inside the container
RUN yarn install

# Remove .npmrc or .yarnrc after installation
RUN rm -f .npmrc

# Build the Next.js app
RUN yarn build

# Override the default entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT []

EXPOSE 3000

# Specify the command to run when the container starts
CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

note: i don't think that `ENTRYPOINT []` did anything. If i inspect the image in docker, an image history appears, which displays a list of commands and one them displays:

`/bin/sh -c #(nop) ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]`

deployment.yaml (angular brackets are used to obfuscate details):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: <placeholder>
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: <placeholder>
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: <placeholder>
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: <container_name>
          image: <container_url>.azurecr.io/<repo_name>:<version_#>
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: <secret>
```

service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: <app_name>
spec:
  selector:
    app: <app_name>
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000 # Match this to the containerPort above.
  type: LoadBalancer
```

My nextjs app is just what's generated from running `npx create-next-app@latest`, no other modifications to the code.

Any thoughts on how to resolve the error? Or perhaps, how to further diagnose the error?

Otherwise, if you know of any good (fairly recent) guides/ articles that go into depth on how to dockerize nextjs for Azure containers and deploy them on azure kubernetes that would also be helpful.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There are quite a few answers on that question, including a few mentioning issues with the script. Can you run other commands in the container? Can you provide the script? Please see [mcve] for details on providing a reproducible example.

Comment: I can run other commands, which would you like me to run? 

As for scripts, I provided the dockerfile and deployment.yaml, but i'll weave in the service.yaml as well, which are the only scripts aside from the nextjs app, which was generated from `npx create-next-app@latest`. Was there another script you would like me to provide?

Comment: (btw, what's with using a bash shebang on a dockerfile? dockerfiles aren't bash scripts -- for that matter, they aren't executable at all, and shouldn't have shebangs)

Comment: Personally, I'd worry about `COPY . .` and carefully inspect everything it's transferring that your later steps may try to execute -- if you're copying an executable or library compiled for your host OS, you need to worry about whether that's compatible with your target. It's not _just_ architecture differences that can cause an exec format error; OS differences can do it too.

Comment: The error message is complaining about `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh`, not the Dockerfile. The Dockerfile is not a shell script.

Comment: @BMitch, definitely; I wasn't meaning to imply that that was the OP's problem, just stating that it was an odd choice.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think I was echoing your comments (+1 from me). The OP implied they provided the Dockerfile and yaml files when I asked about their script, missing that the error was pointing to `docker-entrypoint.sh`.

Comment: @BMitch apologies, i didn't mean to disregard your request for the script file `docker-entrypoint.sh`. 

I didn't provide it because i didn't create it and it's not in my local project directory, so i wasn't sure. I tried to locate it locally using the following command:

`ls -l /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh`

but i got this output: `ls: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: No such file or directory.` 

It's my first time coming across this script, so i don't know anything about it, and i'm not really sure how to proceed or debug it.

Comment: If so, then `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh` is from the `node:16` base image. That indicates the platform of the shell listed in that file is likely throwing the error. What's the output of `docker run --entrypoint file ${image_name} /bin/dash` ?

Comment: `docker run --entrypoint file ${image_name} /bin/dash` output:
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "file": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

Comment: i also tried `docker run --platform linux/amd64 -it --rm --entrypoint file ${image_name} /bin/dash` and `docker run --platform linux/amd64 -it --rm --entrypoint file ${image_name} /usr/local/bin/`, got the same error: exec: "file": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

Comment: It's in the `node:16` image that I just pulled. At this point, I'd recommend updating the question with the full output of the image inspect so the environment, history, and layer hashes, can be compared with expected values.

Comment: OH, I see now. If i go into the container cli and navigate to /usr/local/bin/ I can see the docker-entrypoint file, and that the entrypoint is being set by the base image. The output of the entrypoint.sh is consistent with the repo: https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/bdf5edb771596f7e3998ff318c3098850261b17b/18/bookworm/docker-entrypoint.sh . I tried changing node versions to `node-18`, and adding `RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh` to ensure it has proper permissions but still nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By and large, the error `exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error` commonly arises due to a CPU/architecture mismatch between the machine that builds the image and the host machine that runs the container.

In this particular case, the error persisted because the `imagePullPolicy` was not explicitly set in the `deployment.yaml` file. When not set, Kubernetes defaults to the `IfNotPresent` policy, which means it will only pull the image if it isn't already present on the node. Thus, even if an updated image is pushed to the repository of the container registry, a pod could still use the cached old version of the image.

To ensure the latest version of the image is always used, set the `imagePullPolicy` to `Always`:

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
    - name: <container_name>
      image: <image_url>:<version_tag>
      imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Specifically in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS), if the image is not set to be pulled every time, the node will cache the image. This means that if the pod is deleted and recreated, it will use the cached image rather than fetching it again from the container registry.