# exec /usr/local/bin/firebase: exec format error

Tags: firebase, docker, firebase-tools

I am tying to build an [Alpine](https://www.alpinelinux.org)-based Docker image for [Firebase CLI tool](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools). Below is the *Dockerfile*:

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk update; \
  apk add --no-cache openjdk21-jre; \
  wget --output-file /usr/local/bin/firebase https://firebase.tools/bin/linux/latest; \
  chmod +x /usr/local/bin/firebase;
EXPOSE 9099
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 5001
EXPOSE 8085
EXPOSE 9000
EXPOSE 9199
EXPOSE 9299
EXPOSE 4000
VOLUME [ "/opt/firebase" ]
WORKDIR /opt/firebase
CMD [ "firebase" ]
```

Not much is happening here as you can see. However, I get `exec format error` when I run a container off of this image. I have been searching for solutions all over the internet. And while I see this ["architecture mismatch"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73285601/11317272) issue causing this kind of error, that does not seem to be applicable for me. As I am getting this error while building the image and running the container on the same machine. Can anyone point me at the exact issue this is happening for?

Comment: You can still get that error if you've downloaded an x86 binary via `wget` on to an ARM-based host (like a Raspberry Pi or an M1 Mac), or _vice versa_.

Comment: Note: my host machine is running Windows 10 Pro and I'm using WSL2 (Ubuntu) environment to build Docker images.

Comment: What happens when you retrieve this binary outside of docker and run it in WSL?

Comment: It gives me the expected output without any error.

Comment: What kind of executable does `file /usr/local/bin/filebase` (installing libmagic and tools if necessary to run this inside the container) say you have? What kind of system does `uname -a`, again run _inside the container_, say you have? Does `ldd /usr/local/bin/firebase`, _when run inside the Docker container_, say the executable's dependencies are all present? (Using alpine makes that a _particularly_ sensitive question, since it comes with less than the usual set of distro-provided tools).

Comment: Indeed, since you know that ubuntu can run the executable you're downloading, why are you using an alpine container instead of an ubuntu one in the first place?

Comment: 1. `/usr/local/bin/firebase: ASCII text`. 2. `Linux 626360de9d26 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Thu Oct 5 21:02:42 UTC 2023 x86_64 Linux`. 3. `/lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1: /usr/local/bin/firebase: Not a valid dynamic program`. Not sure if that's a *Yes* or a *No*. 4. Because I want to keep my image size small. I tried using Debian's `slim` images, but the required `default-jre` package wasn't available in any of the variants (not even in the `backports` ones) to install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `firebase` binary is **NOT** supported by Alpine Linux yet. So I switched to `debian`'s `slim` image and I got it working. This is the *Dockerfile* I've used:

```
FROM debian:stable-slim
RUN apt update && apt install --yes default-jre
ADD --chmod=700 https://firebase.tools/bin/linux/latest /usr/local/bin/firebase
EXPOSE 9099
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 5001
EXPOSE 8085
EXPOSE 9000
EXPOSE 9199
EXPOSE 9299
EXPOSE 4000
ENTRYPOINT [ "firebase" ]
```