"exec format error" when trying to build a docker image
I'm using rosetta 2 on a Mac M1 % uname -m: x86_64
% arch: i386 I'm not sure if that is important but it feels like an architecture issue. I've tried docker system prune -a but doesn't do anything. I know it's nothing wrong with the image or dockerfile itself because others use the same repo and have no issues so it has to be a local issue.
=> ERROR [builder 3/7] RUN apt-get update      && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install apt-utils curl libgomp1 build-essen  0.4s
 => ERROR [runtime 3/8] RUN apt-get update      && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install apt-utils curl libgomp1 build-essen  0.4s
------                                                                                                                                  
 > [builder 3/7] RUN apt-get update      && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install apt-utils curl libgomp1 build-essential libpq-dev     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*:
0.355 exec /bin/sh: exec format error
------
------
 > [runtime 3/8] RUN apt-get update      && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install apt-utils curl libgomp1 build-essential libpq-dev     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*:
0.351 exec /bin/sh: exec format error
------
Dockerfile:40
--------------------
  39 |     
  40 | >>> RUN apt-get update  \
  41 | >>>     && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install apt-utils curl libgomp1 build-essential libpq-dev \
  42 | >>>     && apt-get clean \
  43 | >>>     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
  44 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update      && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install apt-utils curl libgomp1 build-essential libpq-dev     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
make: *** [build] Error 1


likely an architecture issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73285601/docker-exec-usr-bin-sh-exec-format-error
