Dockerfile python building fail
when I wanted to build my docker app and followed the steps from the official docker resources exactly as told, I got this error:
=> ERROR [4/5] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt                                                                                                                                                   0.4s 
------
 > [4/5] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt:
0.315 exec /bin/sh: exec format error
------
Dockerfile:6
--------------------
   4 |
   5 |     COPY requirements.txt ./
   6 | >>> RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
   7 |
   8 |     COPY . .
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

this it the dockerfile:
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "./manage.py" ]

I do not have a clue as to why this happens
tried restarting and recreating the dockerfile

Wrong architecture. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73285601/docker-exec-usr-bin-sh-exec-format-error

yeah, when I wanna check I get this however: PS C:\Users----\moonviewer> docker image inspect rethkevin/rf:v1
[]
error during connect: this error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.45/images/rethkevin/rf:v1/json": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.

How and on what kind of machine (OS, architecture) are you building?
Does the Python container image you are trying to use support your architecture?

Linux x64 would be prefered

I'm also certain that it is the right architecture

the issue is also python specific
